# Must a sapient species rely entirely on language to advance?

Tags: science-based, technology, language, intelligence, sapience

Humans, unlike other intelligent species, have a unique reliance on our language. Is this required? Could a species, with language, realistically advance to human-level technology without having a complete reliance on language as in humans?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "complete reliance," but I'd say language is 100% necessary for an advanced (technologically), intelligent society.

Comment: It depends on your definition of language. Anything that allows communication can substitute language. However, anything that allows communication may be called language (sign language, ...). So, is the question whether communication is necessary or whether a species may communicate via images, signing, radio waves, ...?

Comment: Humans have trouble imagining non-human-like sapient aliens. We imagine that they're all individuals, participate in a monkey-society, and that intelligence even means things like consciousness. Why would there even have to be more than one mind? If there is only one mind, who would it communicate with? Can there be intelligence, but no mind at all? This forum probably isn't suitable for discussing such things.

Comment: I mean... doesn't telepathy serve the same function?

Comment: "Complete reliance"??  *We* don't *completely rely* on language!!!!!

Comment: @RonJohn I missed the part where I didn't have to completely rely on language to earn my degree in Electrical Engineering. Remember what Ichthy said, "realistically advance to human-level technology."

Comment: @JBH you *observed* and *mimicked*, didn't you?

Comment: @JohnO One god-like being might not require "language," (although how such a mind would create human-level technology without the capacity to comprehend quantity), but that hasn't been specified by the OP. Despite having answered the question, I can see the point of the close voters. Without specification of the species, this question is (as you say) to vague to adequately answer. Does God need language? Personally, I don't know, but it's hard to imagine a being that can comprehend how to build a nuclear reactor and not have the ability to work out how to teach another being that fact.

Comment: @RonJohn Heck no. You can't observe and mimic the deposition of negative ions in a positive substrate. I can watch the machine do it, but it's happening on a microscopic scale - invisible to the naked eye. It's ***impossible*** to learn how to dope a substrate through observation and mimicry. Now... I did *observe a text book* and I *duplicated what it taught me....* But that required the use of symbolic expression (aka language). There's a fair amount of current human technology that was predicted mathematically before we could build it factually.

Comment: @JBH I said nothing about god-like beings. I simply mentioned those who have no individuality. Your ability to think as if you weren't human is rather limited even at the best of times, and it's not the best of times when you've been consuming trash science fiction for 4 decades or however long it is. Why would a grove of sapient fir trees need individuality? Each new dendroid that sprouts adds computing capacity... there's no reason to instantiate a new personality. If there was a need for a new personality, why would that need to be a one-to-one with dendroids?

Comment: @JohnO Well... you did. "If there is only one mind, who would it communicate with?" I'm responding in the context of the OP's question - a single mind with no one to communicate with that has *realistically achieved human-level technology.* That's god-like. The comment discussion has no meaning (or usefulness) if we're not talking in the context of the OP's question. Are we?

Comment: @JBH You're confused. A single mind that inhabits a world (or some habitable space) might very well in a stone-age. It might in the future achieve human level intelligence, it might not. Such a species (or likely, we're talking about a biology that doesn't even fit well into a species classification system) wouldn't be god-like in any of the colloquial ways, and might well be on a course towards stagnation or extinction if intelligence eventually requires multiple minds to advance. A question I'd say has yet to be answered definitively.

Comment: @JBH have you *ever*, in your *entire life* mimicked something to learn it?  If so, then you don't "rely **entirely**" on language.

Comment: @RonJohn Ichthy isn't asking about relying entirely on language or not. He/she is *specifically* asking if that reliance is needed to achieve human-level technology. Can you point to even one aspect of a cell phone that could have been developed without the use of some kind of cue or symbology?

Comment: @JBH I'm being pedantic about the absoluteness of the word "entirely".

Comment: @RonJohn Fair enough, but the least you could be is pedantic within the scope of the question. I'm sitting in a chair right now. I'm sitting entirely in that chair right now. (And I have to admit that I'm banging my head entirely on my desk due to a spate of unproductive comments made in the last 36 hours.)

Comment: @Ichthys King The only way I can think of that this could work is if your species lived incredibly long lifespans, think hundreds or likely thousands of years, were extremely curious and intelligent, and spent their lives exploring and studying the nature of the universe around them and applying the knowledge they learn.  They all advance in isolation of each other (because any form of communication between them would be considered a language).  They would also have to be able to do all the work to construct this technology alone (because coordinating a team of workers requires communication.

Comment: In other words, the lightbulb has been invented thousands or even millions of times because they cannot share their discoveries with each other.  Maybe they don’t want to share their discoveries with each other.  Basically, what you’re looking for is a race of hyper individualistic, hyper intelligent, long-lived, Mary Sue hermits.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'd say "yes".

We can learn to perform complex works by observing someone, or even analyzing the things someone made in the past (someone we have never met), and see what works and what doesn't... and even improve that design.

That's the reason why *stealing technology* works. While communication about a technical advancement might be helpful, it isn't *needed*.

There always has been a lot of learning with no communication going on, and a lot of communication without language being involved.

Comment: This received the coveted green checkmark? Apparently Ichthy just wanted someone to agree with him/her. I dare you to steal mathematical secrets without having any language with which to express or comprehend mathematics. I dare you to steal the plans for and comprehend how to build a nuclear power plant *without the use of language.* I'm an electrical engineer, nobody can learn what I did designing integrated circuits by simply looking over my shoulder. -1 for not thinking through what Ichthy meant when he/she said, "realistically advance to human-level technology."

Comment: No scientist ever wants to monitor mouse clicking or trial-and-error VHDL hacking of those pesky electrical engineers ;) but yes, analyzing working processor designs is so common that nowadays active countermeasures are being employed.

Comment: Stealing technology without understanding it can lead quite easily to cargo cults (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult). You need to be more or less on the same level (as the one you stole the technology from) to understand what you have stolen, and to get to that level you very probably have *already* needed language.

Comment: @JBH Are questioners always expected to accept an answer?

Comment: @TheCommander The good, the bad, and the ugly. Stack Exchange requires questions to be asked *from the perspective* of the OP selecting one, best answer. However, there is no obligation to select a best answer. However, however, when one is selected, logic, courtesy, and the shear weight of humanity would suggest *that it make sense.* This one doesn't. Other answers said "yes" and provided substantially better rationale for the answer. This one is filled with falsehoods and poor reasoning. Anyone who thinks "trial-and-error VHDL hacking" is ever successful has (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ...never done it and a picture of a chip layout means nothing if you don't understand what you're looking at. You haven't stolen *technology* if you can't build the chip. What @jvb said *doesn't make sense* and demonstrates that they have no experience in the field or the art. I can steal the radio out of someone's car without saying a word... but the OP's goal is to attain human-level technology. So if I didn't know how the radio worked before I stole it, I might duplicate how it was hooked up to get that one radio working again - but without the education I have, I could never duplicate it.

Comment: @jbh I would have thought an electrical engineer should know. Have a look at _hardware analysis_, see [here](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/pubs/usenix08/mifare.html) for a unclassified one - analyzing a crypto protocol by looking at the chip. Conclusion: "Reverse-engineering functionality from silicon implementations can be done cheaply". It's not about stealing the chip, it's not about copying it; it's about understanding _what it does_.

Comment: @JBH please would you state what exactly you believe to be "falsehoods and poor reasoning", without resorting to ad hominem attacks? Full disclosure: I've actually done+published research in that field... did we maybe meet before?

Comment: @jvb `an electrical engineer should know` An electrical engineer *does know.* You just suggested *I go read something.* A crypto-protocol requires *symbology* that can't be manipulated or understood without linguistic constructs. Please listen to yourself, `I've actually done+published [sic] research...,` with language, of course. None of what you've suggested is possible to the extent required by the OP without some form of language. If you believe I've been unrealistic with my assertions, please point me to an explanation of reverse engineering *that doesn't use language.*

Comment: @JBH ...I brought up the "publishing" because you were still claiming me not to have experience in the field, and issuing falsehoods (your uncourtly words). But that's not what the question is about. See, _understanding_ doesn't have to be "in language". Do you believe the ability of e.g. "bicycling" is conferred by some magic words - if someone only has heard the right words, the right argumentation, he or she will be able to ride a bike? I don't deny words might be useful in _talking about_ that later, but are they necessary to "steal the technology"? No, they aren't.

Comment: @jvb Bicycling is a skill, and it mostly utilizes muscle memory, while technology relies heavily on conceptual knowledge and conceptual memory. Skills can very often be learned just by means of observation and mirroring (even animals can do it, eg. monkeys learn how to crack nuts with rocks this way), but conceptual knowledge is quite different beast, and you cannot absorb such understanding merely via observation and imitation.

Answer (score 9):

Current level of technology has been achieved with education and cooperation. Both rely on language. It seems that as science goes forward, language is needed more and more: to transfer the information to new generations, and to work together.

People can dig a ditch together without saying a word the entire day, but building a house together without any communication might be a disaster. The more complex the work becomes, the more essential communication becomes, and communication needs language.

So, I would extrapolate from this that use of language corresponds to how far technology can advance.

Of course super-intelligent intuitively cooperative species can potentially advance further even if they use language less, but the ultimate power of any species comes from combined effort, making language quite essential.

Answer (score 9):

**What's a language?**

It is impossible to achieve humanity's current level of technology without the following:

1. A means of preserving information.
2. A means of exchanging information.

The word "language" is meaningless.<sup>1, 2</sup> "Language" can be anything. By definition, if you can accomodate both of the aforementioned requirements, what you have is a "language" no matter how it's implemented (sight, sound, smell, touch, telepathy, empathy, spiritualism, clairvoyance, or any unusually erudite use of invective).

**Answer to your question: no**

Consequently, the trivial answer to your question is, "no, it's impossible to achieve humanity's current level of technology without language" because anything that meets the aforementioned requirements can be legitimately defined as a "language."

*From a very simple perspective, it's impossible to advance without the ability to explain to the next generation why they shouldn't attack the really big lizard with really long teeth without the whole tribe helping. You can use sign language. You can use grunts and whistles. You can demonstrate the basic problem by tying your neighbor, whose small pet lizard keeps defecating on your lawn, to a tree and waiting for the big lizard to show up (which would be very educational). Those are all examples of "language" because information was exchanged and preserved. Without those abilities every generation must re-learn the same basic information — without help. Could any number of generations of creatures achieve a successful moon launch without the aid of exchanging and preserving information? I'm asserting no.*

**A Quick Note:** One more thing. While a great amount of knowledge can be achieved by simple trial-and-error, I have a hard time believing any species could get to where humanity is *without mathematics.* I dare anyone to try and educate another in the mystical art of partial differentiation without any use of language by any definition. The idea of mathematics without a written symbology (aka, "language") is, IMO, unbelievable.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> *And it doesn't help that you didn't explain what you mean by "language." Binary programming is a "language." So's French. My wife has a certain look to her eye that is occasionally sent in my direction and I assure you, it's "language."*</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> *@AlexP is being a bit literal, so I'll explain. Obviously the word "language" has a definition—and a pretty useful one at that. But in the context of Ichty's question, the idea of language is meaningless because any method of preserving and exchanging information can be defined as a language. In short, Ichty and AlexP are both being too literal when the reality of what's necessary to achieve a successful moon launch requires, well... language. "A word by any other name will still tell you where to buy lunch." Even if that "word" is a "picture" better known as a "map."*</sub>

Comment: Ah yes, the Wife look. A terribly powerful and devastating weapon - that should it be misused or fall into the wrong hands could bring total annihilation. It is only eclipsed by the Dad-Look.

Comment: I don't think I would define the neighbor being eaten by a dinosaur thing as "language", per se, but it's also not a very useful pedagogical tool. I mean, you only have so many neighbors.

Comment: The word language is most definitely **not** meaningless, at least not in linguistics or in informatics (= computer science for Americans). And "a means of preserving information" does not need to be a language in any meaning of the word language; for example, a photograph or a video clip preserve information in an entirely non-linguistic way.

Comment: @AlexP Thanks for making my point.

Comment: You know, @AlexP, from the perspective of the OP's question, you're dead wrong. A photograph is just a more complex form of pictograph. Once a repeatable context and meaning is identified, it's just another letter in a complex alphabet. Language can be construed and constructed from anything unless you get too caught up in the idea that "language here on Earth only means *this."* But that argument doesn't benefit the OP other than to underscore a second or third time the answer, "no."

Comment: This is where meme theory (the original one, not pics with funny captions) comes into play. The idea being that memes are "idea fragments" that duplicate, mutate and ultimately evolve just like genes, except a lot faster. Without memes there's no advanced culture, and the encoding of those memes for transfer can always be used to DEFINE the notion of language.

Comment: @AlexP That's kinda the problem though, "language" has like a million incompatible definitions, for example in formal language theory a language is firmly defined as "any subset of a free monoid over a finite set of terminal symbols", so for example the empty set is a language, so is the set containing the empty string (and a different one), but also the binary representation of the Fibonacci sequence over the symbols 0 and 1, and good luck with that definition in a course on Medieval Church Latin. Or indeed anywhere else, except in formal language theory, where it makes perfect sense.

Comment: @biziclop: Having different meanings in different disciplines is perfectly normal, and is definitely different from being meaningless. For example, the word energy has entirely different meanings in theology and in physics, and the word substance has entirely different meanings in metaphysics and in chemistry, yet nobody feels confused.

Comment: @AlexP If you're not given the context, they're as good as meaningless though. You yourself demonstrated this when you said a movie or a photo is not a language for example, which is a fair interpretation but it would be a shock to people studying the language of movies and photography.

Comment: @biziclop: The study of the language of movies is a not a study of language; it is a fancy name for either the study of film making technique, or the study of film criticism. The phrase is metaphorical, not intended to be interpreted literally.

Comment: I'd add _0. A means of encoding information_. That is, symbols, representation. Words are symbols for what they mean. Perhaps you included that in "preserving", but I interpreted it as "persisting".

Comment: @PabloH persisting = preserving. Encoding concepts into symbology is merely the process used to achieve #1 and #2. My assertion is that anything you use to regularly exchange and preserve information eventually becomes a language. Show me a way one thinks that wouldn't be true and I'll explain how the demonstration will eventually become a language.

Answer (score 6):

It is not necessary. Knowledge is just electrons encoded in sugar. So anything that can just double the memory sugar and inject it into another being, can in theory share the knowledge. It would be there instantly, without a "learning" period.

Also the transport mechanism can be very different. It needs to leave the blood stream, so in theory it could be a mosquito, transporting learning, or leeches.

It could also go wrong, sharing traumatic memories or private memories. Ever wanted to remember, how your parents conceived you? Or how grandpa was almost split in two with a big sword, and just passed on the memory of it in a blood conserve after death?

Well now you can.

Comment: But isn't encoding a language? How could computers understand that "10.13" is "CR.LF" without a language, which is called encoding? Encoding, being a system of communication, is a language; and without a system of communication, electrons in sugar are just noise.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encoding_(memory).. i dare to assume that the memory encoding is universal. What is needed is additional information about location to restore the memory. There i have a plothole.. feel free to fill it

Comment: I think the point is that transporting knowledge directly from one brain (or any other thought engine) to another is not language.

Comment: Agree - a baby knows how to do things via genetic encoding. A monkey baby knows how to hold on to its mother immediately after birth, but a human baby doesn't. That knowledge wasn't transferred by language. Lately, we have seen that brain patterns can be read and understood electronically, or that dolphins can transmit information about how the bottom of the ocean looks by clicks and sounds, surely that isn't language.

Comment: Having knowledge alone isn't the same as being able to make use of said knowledge, You could have all the the mathematical know-how in the world inside your brain but not be able to effectively use it for computation without a pencil and paper for which you need language. If you have all the brain but insufficient brawn then you need help from others which means you need some form of communication.

Comment: A hard disk can contain vast quantities of information, but it can't do anything with it. It's the ability to use existing knowledge to develop new knowledge which language particularly enables. To some extent it's possible by demonstrating to others, but that breaks down for more complex operations.

Comment: I see your points, they're good ones; that transporting knowledge directly from one brain to the other is not language; that genetic encoding isn't a communication language; etc. I understand better, thank you. (The answer could be improved with this clarity.)

Comment: @NovaDev How is «dolphins can transmit information about how the bottom of the ocean looks by clicks and sounds, _surely that isn't language_» different from the clicks in the [Xhosa language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xhosa_language)? I don't think it is. I think that those clicks are clearly a language - see [WP:Whale vocalization#Purpose...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whale_vocalization#Purpose_of_whale-created_sounds). (Cetaceans also use sound for echolocation; which is not a language.)

Comment: @ANeves - I mean like sonar/radar isn't a language, as much as a literal and physical representation of what a given piece of the bottom of the ocean looks like. Language is a symbolic referential use of sound that doesn't exactly transmit, whereas the way dolphins transmit information is more like sending a picture back and forth. I don't need language to understand what a picture shows. Dolphins can reproduce an image and transmit it, but they also use language separately.

Comment: @NovaDev I understand your point, but strongly disagree. I think that the ecolocation by the dolphin itself is purely not-language and the dolphin creates knowledge internally. But that communicating that knowledge to other dolphins with clicks and sounds is communication and thus necessitates language; I think it *is* a referential use of sound. Like I also think that the bees' "[waggle dance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waggle_dance)" is a form of communication that necessarily includes a language.

Comment: RE: bees, this quote implies symbolic referential use of communication: «Elements of the round dance also provide information regarding the forager's subjective evaluation of the food source's profitability.» - [WP:Round Dance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round_dance_(honey_bee)) (Sound is not required for language. There's written comments in SE, there's Braille, Sign Language, military hand signals, smoke signals, bird dancing, different chicken clucking types, beaver tail slaps, etc.)

Comment: Maybe we should move this to chat, if we want to continue. It's a very interesting topic, but it's difficult and lengthy to understand and argue the semantics of what is and is not a language.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what we can observe here on Earth, there are species capable of making and using technology (crows, chimpanzees among them) but none of them, despite having communication capabilities though less advanced that those possessed by humans, has advanced to anything more advanced than our early stone age (and I am being generous).

Of course extrapolating general trends and laws out of a single data point doesn't give a sound grounding to any statement, however based on the above it seems that advanced communication capabilities help in moving technology forward: they make it easier to transmit knowledge and refine it, by building mental models.

Comment: My question was about the reliance on language, not how advanced it is

Comment: What do you consider "reliance on language", then?

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, if their brains are identical or close to

I take 'language' to mean a mutually intelligible encoding/decoding system for the transmission of information.

As humans, we need language because we don't have identical brains; we devise common signifiers and a learnable syntax so that we can get information that's similar from my brain to yours, or vice versa.

If a species has a perfectly uniform brain, you could just import raw data directly from one individual to another, just like you can do with e.g. some PLCs, or a hard disk image. No encoding needed; you're transferring a state of mind straight from one to another.

[You could point at the transmission medium or even the brain state and call it 'language', but IMO seamless copying of raw brain and mind states pushes the concepts of encoding and syntax, and thus language, past the point of meaningfulness. I don't regard the Mona Lisa or a photo as language, except under artificially contrived circumstances.]

Note, this requires a materialist universe where brain states = mind states. If there are souls or any other higher realities where consciousness resides independent of brain states, this won't work. My world view rejects this requirement, but it's OK for sci fi.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to say 'No'.

Here's my rationale:

Let's take a moment to define language - there's not just verbal language, there are other forms of communication that if sufficiently developed could be considered as a form of Language -  for instance ASL.

So, even if we are considering only Verbal Communication, any other form of communication that is advanced enough becomes language.

Then we have to consider what the most basic function of communication is - to get more than one person to do something.

Even for non-social species - vocalization or scent marking can mean: "I'm here, stay away" or "I'm here and available"

Then we work up to social interaction and team work: Lions, Monkeys, Wolves, Orcas etc. All have a language of sorts that allows them to co-operate to achieve a goal.

After that, Language develops to teach others. For example different regional pods of Orcas have different 'languages' and have developed different hunting strategies, which they teach to their young.

Co-operation and education are the foundation of starting an advanced society. After that you could add in Tool Use and then finally you could add knowledge preservation (e.g. writing).

All of those require a form of Language to develop.

Whether it's, verbal, physical, psychic etc.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of in which sapient species advance without a language is to have that language encoded in something else as suggested in another answer.

We know for sure that as you increase the complexity of anything, more configurations are needed to describe and study it. Think of the deuteron nucleus (one proton and one neutron) versus Uranium (92 protons and 143 neutrons for just one of the isotopes). You need 6 coordinates for the former and 705 for the latter. Building one wall is simple but a house is complex. Making a wheel spin is easy but a vehicle is complex and so on.

So you definitely need ways to describe and transmit information. Information needs some mean to communicate it. Physical language is one but we have already invented Morse code, the binary system, hexadecimal, electromagnetic waves, etc. Thus, the beings can communicate digitally or even at the quantum level (or via EM waves!)

Answer (score 0):

It is for a species that **resembles** modern humans in **niche**.

---

I'd say it is a requirement for humans in the modern era, however, they could still advance all the way to civilization with just humming and freeform sign (not an actual language like the sign languages).

Also, they can still biologically advance. They can remove the annoying extremely long gestation times and extremely slow growth rates. Though they will eventually reach a big roadblock.

---

As for non-human niche beings, if the story is supernatural, you can have:

- Powerful psychic beings, like angels , who **can** live **solitary** and have the intelligence, power, and lifespan to just make civilisation's systems themselves with AI  and **subservient** lifeforms.
- Hive minds or single soul beings. These live indefinitely, and are spread over a colossal range. They can make civilisation's systems using their intelligence, animating abilities, and lifespan.

Answer (score 0):

Human technology is limited by lifespan. Language allows us to pass information between individuals, shortening the time required for an individual to be capable of contributing to the species' advancement.

With a vastly longer lifespan it may be possible for a species to reach current human technology levels within one lifetime, requiring almost no communication at all.

Also, other forms of communication that can not be called language may enable a species to discard language as the primary means of information transfer. Allow for an effect like memory transfer, hive minds, knowledge inheritance, etc. and language becomes the inefficient route.

Comment: There are still high hurdles to overcome even with long lifespans. You need to be able to recall AND process everything you have ever learned AND carry out the required work in a a reasonable amount of time. If you need to use references or computational assistance (from a pencil and paper to super computer) then you need language, even if it's just to communicate to yourself. If you need to cooperate simply to get more manipulators on the job you also need language. A singular entity or individual that does not need any of this assistance would be nearly godlike.

Comment: If you had databanks and computation that could directly pipe data into your brain or nearly entirely dependent on artificial manipulators then you could get around this, but then how did you *advance* to get that equipment to begin with?

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of information transfer that could arise organically. E.g. vulcan mind meld, the Hive Queen's telepathy, etc.

Comment: That only really eases the "teaching" element but still does not overcome memory or computational limitations of the entitys' mind, for which you would still need language to overcome until you get to mundane telepathic equipment. There also isn't always another being there to tell you what things are on equipment, facilities, and stuff. Unless you feel like having elevator men everywhere.